# What is the difference between giving character with quotes as key and just character as key of property of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, object, ecmascript-6

1. `const first= {a: 2, b: 3}`
2. `const second= {"a": 2, "b": 3}`

Even though both examples given above print the same in console, I can't access the values of those objects the same way. To access the key of `first` object, I have to write `console.log( first.a )` and for second object `console.log( first[a] )`.

So if they are printing the same, why should I have to access them in different way. If the keys in `first` object aren't characters then what are they...

Below code is the reason why I got this question

```
const maxchar = (str)=>{
  let charCount = {}
  for (let index = 0; index < str.length; index++) {
    const char = str[index]
    charCount[char] = charCount[char]+ 1|| 1 //can't access char as charCount.char
  }
  return charCount
}
```

Comment: 1. and 2. are *identical* - there is literally no difference. The quotes are optional in this case. `first.a` and `first[a]` are completely different. The second one will [dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4244896) and in this case the variable is `a`. So, depends on what the variable contains. Your code also does dynamic accessing by a variable, there isn't a `.char` property on that object. The key would be whatever the *variable* called `char` contains. I'm not clear how that relates to the beginning of the question, though.

Comment: You are trying `console.log(first[a])`. Did you mean `console.log(first['a'])` (not the quotes around `a`)?

Comment: **I think you just** ***nailed it,*** **Thijs!**  (Show-of-hands how many people at first failed to notice that `a` is a *variable* reference?  Yes, my hand is raised.)  When you use "dot" notation, the language understands that the identifier following the dot refers to a member.  But when you use "array" notation, the value within the brackets is an *expression,* whose value must match the name of a member.  *(Most likely, JavaScript printed an error-message to the console log which the OP failed to notice, "and just kept right on going," as JS always does.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first question: there is no difference between your 1st and 2nd example.

For your second question, let's look at this small example:

```
charCount = { a: 2, b:3 }
char = 'a'
print(charCount[char]) // 2
print(charCount.char) // error
```

As pointed out in the comment, when you call `charCount[char]`, it will [dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable). What it does is just simply replace the variable `char` with its current value (which is `a` in this case). So, the call becomes `charCount['a']`, and you got the result.

When you call `charCount.char`, it literally tries to access the property named `char` of the object `charCount`. In this case, that property does not exist, which is why you got an error.